# is PERT/CPM still being used?

Tags: project-management

I wonder whether PERT/CPM is still being used, or, is it an ancient methodology for the world of today? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Project (and a variety of other project management tools) offer Gantt charts, which as far as I can tell are equivalent to PERT charts.

I use them on 6-12 month tasks building complex software systems.  We usually define several hundred tasks, that do have many order dependencies.

This is a completely different perspective than another poster's answer who says "for the software part of the project, ... there aren't any order dependencies".   His world is sure different than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Although I had never heard of  CPM (Critical Path Method) and PERT (Programme Evaluation Review Technique) and thought you were asking about an old operating system it appears that these techniques are still in use or at least still taught.

Doing and advanced search on Google and limiting the query to the last year resolved to 731,000 results.

I also noticed that there are a great number of software options, including methods to make office produce the required charts and documents.

The only restriction I found was that it is generally not used for very large projects as the graphs tend to get too large to be easily printed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I find PERT pretty silly for the software part of a project, because there aren't any order dependencies.  You can develop use cases in any order without affecting the total development cost by any measurable amount.  I would even argue that use of PERT charts for software projects is a project smell pointing to a counterproductive project organization.